# Node-REDでWatsonのサービスが使えなくなりました

Tags: bluemix

Node-REDでWatsonの翻訳APIを使った処理を作りました
もともと問題なく動いていたのですが先週からMachine translationがバインドできないというエラーが出ています
どうすれば回避できるでしょうか

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WatsonのMachine Translationは今月正式サービス化されました。
これに伴いAPI仕様も一部更新され、名称もLanguage Translationと変わっています。恐らくこの変更が影響しているものと思われます。

最新のNode-REDはLanguage Translationに対応していますので、あらためてNode-RED Starter（もしくはIoT Foundation Starter）ボイラープレートで環境を作り直してください。

下記URLに関連情報があります。

https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/mtapi/

https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/language-translation/migrating.shtml